# Checkbox validation for checking at least 1 checkbox and at most 3 using javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

At least one checkbox should be checked and at max 3 checkboxes can be checked.

```
function checkout(){
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myCheckBox' );
    if (checkBoxes.length > 3){
        alert('You cannot select more than 3 books');
        return false;
    }
    if (checkBoxes.length == 0) {
        alert('Please select at least 1 book');
        return false;
    }
```

But with this code, irrespective of the number of books I am selecting, the message 'You cannot select more than 3 books is appearing'.

For satisfying the just one checkbox needs to be checked, I used the following code, which worked fine.

```
function checkout(){
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myCheckBox' );
    var isChecked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if ( checkBoxes[i].checked ) {
            isChecked = true;
        };
    };
    if ( isChecked ) {
        alert( 'Your books have been sent to your mail !' );
    } else {
       alert( 'Please, check at least one checkbox!' );
       return false;
    }
}
```

But how do I get the maximum constraint in?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just count the amount of checks in your loop

Comment: @krisph I did i<3 but that didn't work.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".myCheckBox:checked").length`

Comment: @SteveDoson Strictly no Jquery ? or you can use Jquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track! The trick is to simply count the checked books instead of using just a boolean:

```
function checkout(){
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myCheckBox' );
    var nbChecked = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if ( checkBoxes[i].checked ) {
            nbChecked++;
        };
    };
    if ( nbChecked> 3 ) {
        alert( 'You cannot select more than 3 books' );
        return false;
    } else if(nbChecked == 0){
       alert( 'Please, check at least one checkbox!' );
       return false;
    }else{
       //Do what you need for form submission, if needed...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get all the checked checkboxes using `document.querySelectorAll('.myCheckBox:checked');`

```js
function checkout(){
  const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.myCheckBox:checked');

  if (checkBoxes.length > 3){
      alert('You cannot select more than 3 books');
      return false;
  } else if (!checkBoxes.length) {
    alert( 'Please, check at least one checkbox!' );
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox">
<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox">
<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox">
<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox">

<button onClick="checkout()">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a counter to count number of checked

```
function checkout(){
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myCheckBox' );
var isChecked = false;
var numChecked=0;
for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if ( checkBoxes[i].checked ) {
numChecked++;
        isChecked = true;
    };
    };
   if ( (isChecked) && numChecked<3 ) {
    alert( 'Your books have been sent to your mail !' );
   } else {
   alert( 'Please, check at least one checkbox! And not more than 3' );
    return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use counter with loop or use `querySelectorAll` if IE9+, Chrome or Firefox :

```
function checkout(){
    //For all
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName( 'myCheckBox' );
    var length= 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if ( checkBoxes[i].checked ) {
            length++;
        };
    };

    //In IE9+, Chrome or Firefox you can do:
    //var length= document.querySelectorAll('.myCheckBox:checked');

    if ( length> 3 ) {
        alert("You cann't select more than 3");
        return false;
    } else if(length == 0){
       alert("Please, check at least one!");
       return false;
    }
    alert( 'Your books have been sent to your mail !' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indication of whether there is a checkbox there checked is a Boolean flag

```
var isChecked = false;
...
if(isChecked) {
...
```

Now, this is the same logic as asking if `isChecked` is equal to 1.

You can similary count the number of times you come across a checked checkbox. Then it's just a matter of checking if you're ok with the number of checkboxes.

```
if ( checkBoxes[i].checked ) {
    //isChecked = true;
    isChecked++;
};
```

`isChecked` now is counting them

```
if ( isChecked > 0 && isChecked <= 3  ) {
```

to check if they are between 1 and 3 (inclusive)